# Is there an Android version of the SWRevealViewController?

Tags: android, ios

I've been using the SWReveal View Controller as the basis for my app in iOS, and I want to find an analog in Android. I'm hoping to keep the same drawer effect going left and right as appears in John LLuch's SWRevealViewController https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swrevealviewcontroller.

I know you can use a navigation drawers controller to show the left, but that is a pop over. It's not like moving the center screen over to the right. I am also aware of there being the Fixed tabs controller, but those do not allow the center screen to be shown on top either. I am hoping somebody has mimicked a controller in android that allows you to move the three screens as if you were paging between them and still show your center screen at all times.

Please let me know if you guys know of one or know how to make the fixed tabs controller do this.

Answer (score 1):

Google has a navigationDrawer that looks similar to the SWRevealController. However in all our projects we use https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer/tree/master/SimpleSideDrawer as it seems easier to get used to it.

It is not exactly the same but you will get same results. We always make a Base Activity that all the menu activities extends in order to get the actions of the menu.

It is as having a FragmentActivity and on the onCreate method add these:

```
        mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
        mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_left);
        mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_right);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Glad you came back so late to the party, but this looks like it'll help me out! Thanks